# Extending the Validator class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I wanted extend the Validator class in Laravel. However in all examples the make method is used to create a new instance which I can't find in the [Validator source code](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Validation.Validator.html). How can I override this method? The constructor requires a `TranslatorInterface` instance so that doesn't seem to be an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `make` method is actually in [`Illuminate\Validation\Factory`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.html).

If you want to extend this method then you'll need to swap out the IoC binding. Just overload the binding in the container.

```
App::bindShared('validator', function($app)
{
    $validator = new \Your\Validator\Factory($app['translator'], $app);

    if (isset($app['validation.presence']))
    {
        $validator->setPresenceVerifier($app['validation.presence']);
    }

    return $validator;
});
```

Comment: Sounds good, however I don't really understand. What is the Factory($app['translator'], $app)?

Comment: So you need to create your own `Factory` class that extends `Illuminate\Validator\Factory`. Those constructor injected parameters are required. Basically, what you see above was taken from [`Illuminate\Validator\ValidationServiceProvider`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Validation.ValidationServiceProvider.html#14-37).