# How to override View::make() in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, class, extend

I would like to override the default `View::make()` method in Laravel, which can be used to return a view-response to the user.

(I think) I've already figured out that this method is stored inside `Illuminate\View\Factory.php`, and I've been reading about IoC container, while trying to make it work using [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730751/extending-the-validator-class-in-laravel) [similar](http://heera.it/extend-input-class-laravel-4) [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884764/laravel-extend-form-class), but it just won't work.

I've already created a file `App\Lib\MyProject\Extensions\View\Factory.php`, containing the following code:

```
<?php namespace MyProject\Extensions\View;

use Illuminate\View\Factory as OldFactory;

class Factory extends OldFactory {

    public static function make() {
        // My own implementation which should override the default
    }

}
```

where the `MyProject` folder is autoloaded with Composer. But I don't know how to use this 'modified' version of the `Factory` class whenever a static method of `View` (in particular `View::make()`) is being called. Some help would be great!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The call to `View::make` is, in Laravel speak, a call to the `View` facade.  Facades provide global static access to a service in the service container.  Step 1 is lookup the actual class `View` points to

```
#File: app/config/app.php
'aliases' => array(
    'View'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
)
```

This means `View` is aliased to the class `Illuminate\Support\Facades\View`.  If you look at the source of `Illuminate\Support\Facades\View`

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/View.php
class View extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'view'; }

}
```

You can see the facade service accessor is `view`.  This means a call to

```
View::make...
```

is (more or less) equivalent to a call to

```
$app = app();
$app['view']->make(...
```

That is, the facade provides access to the `view` service in the service container.  To swap out a different class, all you need to do is bind a different object in as the `view` service.  Laravel provides an `extend` method for doing this.

```
App::extend('view', function(){
    $app = app();
    // Next we need to grab the engine resolver instance that will be used by the
    // environment. The resolver will be used by an environment to get each of
    // the various engine implementations such as plain PHP or Blade engine.
    $resolver = $app['view.engine.resolver'];

    $finder = $app['view.finder'];

    $env = new \MyProject\Extensions\View($resolver, $finder, $app['events']);

    // We will also set the container instance on this view environment since the
    // view composers may be classes registered in the container, which allows
    // for great testable, flexible composers for the application developer.
    $env->setContainer($app);

    $env->share('app', $app);

    return $env;                
});
```

Notice this is more than just instantiating an object.  We need to instantiate it the same way as the original view service was instantiated and bound (usually with either `bind` or `bindShared`).  You can find that code here

```
#File: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php
public function registerFactory()
{
    $this->app->bindShared('view', function($app)
    {
        // Next we need to grab the engine resolver instance that will be used by the
        // environment. The resolver will be used by an environment to get each of
        // the various engine implementations such as plain PHP or Blade engine.
        $resolver = $app['view.engine.resolver'];

        $finder = $app['view.finder'];

        $env = new Factory($resolver, $finder, $app['events']);

        // We will also set the container instance on this view environment since the
        // view composers may be classes registered in the container, which allows
        // for great testable, flexible composers for the application developer.
        $env->setContainer($app);

        $env->share('app', $app);

        return $env;
    });
}
```

You can test if your binding worked with code like this

```
var_dump(get_class(app()['view']));
```

You should see your class name.  Once your sure the binding has "taken", you're free to redefine whatever methods you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've got everything working now. As a final question: is it good practice to put the App::extend() code inside the /start/global.php file? I wasn't quite sure where to put it, and I think the official documentation points to this location...

Comment: @user132169 It should be fine there, although I think `start/global.php` is going away in Laravel 5.0 (unless you're running the legacy service provider)